# Laravel mix with TinyMCE npm run production - compiled file 'get' undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, tinymce, laravel-mix

I have an issue with **npm run production** when importing **tinymce** plugin.

When I run **npm run dev** everything works as expected. On **npm run production** it compiles successfully but when I open the page with TinyMCE editor it does not load TinyMCE and it gets a javascript error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

I have tried to find a solution and came across similar issues but none of them were related to the **npm run production**.

I have tried to configure webpack uglify with **"ascii_only": true**

Also, I have tried to setup module loaders for tinymce plugin in webpack.mix.js but still no success.

This is how I use it:

```
// app.js
window.tinymce = require('tinymce/tinymce.js');

// webpack.mix.js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/tinymce/icons', 'public/js/icons');
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/tinymce/plugins', 'public/js/plugins');
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/tinymce/skins', 'public/js/skins');
mix.copyDirectory('node_modules/tinymce/themes', 'public/js/themes');
```

Everything works after **npm run dev** as expected but the compiled javascript has an error after **npm run production**.

I guess it can be because of minification but I wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the laravel-mix version, it was 1.7, and the latest is 5.x.

After the update, everything works as expected.